# representing complex boolean operations in human readable format

Tags: boolean

I have a boolean expression: A && (B || C && D)

However A, B, C, and D are quite long character-wise so representing it all in a single line is not possible. Let us assume for this example that A, B, C, and D will be on their own lines.

What is a recommended way to represent this expression using indentations extra parenthesis if necessary, line breaks and so on to maximize human readability.

Comment: I don't know what the best practise would be for the above, but I would recommend hiding all of that logic away in a function with a sensible name. *That* will do wonders for human readability.

Comment: @BurhanAli: Yea, but I still have to do Foo == Bar or something similar as the op for A. I am already refactoring this to be more descriptive and sometimes a few boolean comparisons go with the logical goal of the function.

Comment: How about comments? I usually don't like to figure out what others tried to do, but just read what they intended it to do. At some point it's like "oh that's why there's the || there"

Comment: Comments means more to maintain, I rather be clear. If the logic is some complex math or whatnot, it should be a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, according to your comment, you can use boolean variables such as `bAreFooAndBarEqual`, only have their name carry a deeper meaning, and follow your own naming conventions.

As for your specific example, I would explicitly show that I want the && to take precedence over the ||, and so add another pair of parentheses: `A && (B || (C && D))`.
Then, I would indent on each bracket opening, having the operator to the left of the operands (this is a personal taste, you should see what looks clearest to you):

```
A
&& (B
    || (C
        && D))
```

Of course, this is just a personal taste, and you should think what feels most natural and looks the most clear to you.

Comment: I agree here, I had others recommend the same thing to me.